# How to Install PHP-7.3 pecl packages in Amazon Linux 2018.03?

Tags: php, pecl

Upgrading PHP v5.4 to v7.3 in the Amazon Linux AMI VERSION="2018.03". I am unable to install these following PECL packages to PHP v7.3 as they are not found in the AVAILABLE packages list in the Amazon Linux

The Pecl packages are available still PHP v7.2 in the Amazon Linux

php54-pecl-apc.x86_64

php54-pecl-memcache.x86_64

php54-pecl-oauth.x86_64

Kindly suggest how to install these packages in the amazon linux with respective to PHP v7.3

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using 2018.03? That's a fairly old operating system image. If you can go to Amazon Linux 2, there is an extra channel for 7.3.